# “IEEE 802.11: disassociated” messages when using OVS bridges and wifi APs

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, bridge

I've created an OVS bridge/patch ports on a Raspberry Pi (let's call it Pi3) with 2 wireless adapters (wlan1 and wlan2). I also have 2 Raspberry Pis (Pi1 and Pi2) with 1 wireless adapter each (wlan0) acting as wifi APs using hostapd. My goal is to connect Pi1 and Pi2 with the OVS bridge running on Pi3. I've attached a diagram of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

However, as soon as I activate the 2 APs on the wlan0s of Pi1 and Pi2, and connect wlan1 and wlan2 to them, both APs are flooded with "wlan0: STA ae:26:f7:cc:5f:a5 IEEE 802.11: disassociated" messages. How can I fix this?

Note: I've tried creating the APs and just connecting wlan1 and wlan2 WITHOUT the OVS bridge, and that works fine (no disassociated messages); however, this would obviously result in no connection between Pi1 and Pi2 due to the lack of a bridge.